# Pin Code Activity after some actions

Tags: android, android-activity

I need show PIN Code activity after that (we have App with many Activities):

1. User press hardware button "Home" and go back to App.
2. List item App Screen go to sleep mode then go back.

What ways do I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

capture home key event(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) and  sleep event(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) ,use a variable to record it.
when go back to app activity judge the vaviable and show your PIN code activity.

Comment: Small correction:
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME - doesnt work, need to use KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK + onPause()